# How to use git or hg to track selected files in a folder?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

I have several files in my home folder that I want to have under version control. But if I put the entire folder under version control, on every run of git or hg status, I will see a huge list of untracked files.
Is there a way to use git or hg in such a way that they track only the files specified and ignore every other file?

Answer (score 2):

For both Git and Mercurial you can|have to use the same method:

- Create repository in needed folder (for Git it can be even outside Working Directory)
- Add **all files** in ignore-list
- Specially add *only files, which you want to control*, to VCS

Added files will not be ignored by VCS, all unversioned - ignored by default per-specifcation

Answer (score 0):

For GIT : You can use .gitignore files.

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Alternatively setup individual repositories for the directories you want under version control.

Mercurial probably has something like this: [.hgignore](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/.hgignore).

Probably best to do a google search for this sort of thing. It's a common action for git/hg

Comment: But I want to exclude all files and include only few. I think .gitignore served the opposite purpose.

Comment: Create your repo, add the files you want to track to your index, add all other files to you don't want to trach to .gitignore file (using wildcards etc). Not sure what editor you're using or command line.... I use Eclipse with git support but the process is the same.

Comment: Alternatively, move the files you want to track to a new directory and create your .git/hg repository there...

Comment: Moving to a new directory is not practical. I want to track my ,vimrc, .zshrc and other configuration files. Can't keep them in any other directory.

Comment: @enitihas You might want to use `!.vimrc` in your .gitignore

Comment: Example provided by DavidNeiss above and orb. Use * to ignore ALL files then add !filename to 'not-ignore' these.

Answer (score 0):

Use .gitignore - but tell it to ignore all files and then override that line with another that specifies the files not to ignore by prefacing those files with an exclamation point.

For instance, to track files a and b but not anything else, .gitignore:

```
*
!a
!b
```

So you need to take that list of files that you really want and add them as individual lines, such as the !a and !b lines above.

For more info on gitignore, http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore, specifically section at bottom:

```
Example to exclude everything except a specific directory foo/bar (note the /* - without the slash, the wildcard would also exclude everything within foo/bar):

    $ cat .gitignore
    # exclude everything except directory foo/bar
    /*
    !/foo
    /foo/*
    !/foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to manage/backup dotfiles, which I think is what you mentioned in a comment, there are many people who have provided tutorials or tools to avoid managing an hgignore or a gitignore file by hand. See for example the following tutorial:

[Managing Your Dotfiles](http://www.anishathalye.com/2014/08/03/managing-your-dotfiles/)

which provides some examples (homesick, dotbot, how to use symlinks, etc.).